# Why does TensorFlow always use GPU 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I hit a problem when running TensorFlow inference on multiple-GPU setups.

Environment: Python 3.6.4; TensorFlow 1.8.0; Centos 7.3; 
        2 Nvidia Tesla P4

Here is the nvidia-smi output when the system is free:

```
Tue Aug 28 10:47:42 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.81                 Driver Version: 384.81                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P4            Off  | 00000000:00:0C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    22W /  75W |      0MiB /  7606MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P4            Off  | 00000000:00:0D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    23W /  75W |      0MiB /  7606MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The key statements related to my issue:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"

def get_sess_and_tensor(ckpt_path):
    assert os.path.exists(ckpt_path), "file: {} not exist.".format(ckpt_path)
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(ckpt_path, "rb") as fid1:
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(fid1.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name="")
        sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
        tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("image_tensor:0")
        boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name("detection_boxes:0")
        scores = graph.get_tensor_by_name("detection_scores:0")
        classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

    return sess, tensor, boxes, scores, classes
```

So, the problem is, when set I visible devices to '0,1', even if I set tf.device to GPU 1, when running inference, I see from nvidia-smi that only GPU 0 is used (GPU 0's GPU-Util is high – almost 100% – whereas GPU 1's is 0). Why doesn't it use GPU 1?

I want to use the two GPUs in parallel, but even with the following code, it still uses only GPU 0:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("image_tensor:0")
    boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name("detection_boxes:0")
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    scores = graph.get_tensor_by_name("detection_scores:0")
    classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Wesley

Comment: At least your device name doesn’t comply [with the spec](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/core/util/device_name_utils.h). It should be: `/device:<type>:<num>`. What happens if you use `/device:gpu:{0,1}`? Also see [the note about the overridden device scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#device).

Comment: @agtoever actually, I see the format /gpu:0 in a lot of articles, but I also tried your suggestion, unfortunately, with same issue.

Comment: I think you are using `tf.device` too late. You need to wrap the code that _defines_ the ops. I don't know where this happens with the importing graph stuff, but you might wanna try moving the `with tf.device` wrapper up so that it wraps the `GraphDef` stuff.

Comment: @xdurch0 you mean control the device during the training process? Actually, for training, I didn't specify the visible devices and tf.device, but I don't think it related to this issue, if so, does it also mean it can only use GPU0 for inference  if I specify GPU0 when training?

Comment: What I mean is: You should try something like `with tf.device("/gpu:0"): tf.import_graph_def(...)` etc. So move the `device` stuff up to where you are _building the graph_. Right now you only have it around a part where you are getting tensors from an _already existing graph_. This is too late; by that time the ops are already put on a device (GPU0 by default).

Answer (score 1):

The device names might be different depending on your setup.

Execute:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

And try using the device `name` for your second GPU exactly as listed there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***GPUtil*** package to select unused gpus and filter the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environnement variable.

This will allow you to run parallel experiments on all your gpus.

```
# Import os to set the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import GPUtil

# Set CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER so the IDs assigned by CUDA match those from nvidia-smi
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"

# Get the first available GPU
DEVICE_ID_LIST = GPUtil.getFirstAvailable()
DEVICE_ID = DEVICE_ID_LIST[0] # grab first element from list

# Set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to mask out all other GPUs than the first available device id
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(DEVICE_ID)

# Since all other GPUs are masked out, the first available GPU will now be identified as GPU:0
device = '/gpu:0'
print('Device ID (unmasked): ' + str(DEVICE_ID))
print('Device ID (masked): ' + str(0))

# Run a minimum working example on the selected GPU
# Start a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Select the device
    with tf.device(device):
        # Declare two numbers and add them together in TensorFlow
        a = tf.constant(12)
        b = tf.constant(30)
        result = sess.run(a+b)
        print('a+b=' + str(result))
```

Reference: https://github.com/anderskm/gputil